# pipes causing infinite output

Tags: c, posix, pipe

When I simply pipe ls -l | sort with this, the program just spits out the results from ls -l infinitely.  Can anyone see what's wrong?
Assume that you only have to look at the main function.  This will compile, though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


#define COMMAND_LINE_LENGTH 256
#define HISTORY_LENGTH 10
#define TOKEN_MAX 50
#define DIRECTORY_LENGTH 5
#define DIRECTORY_PREFIX "/bin/"

struct prog_def
{
    //Binary location
    char *bin;

    //Is this program expecting a pipe?
    int expecting_pipe;

    //Arguments
    char *args[TOKEN_MAX + 1];

    pid_t pid;

} prog_def;

int get_prog_defs(const char* buf, struct prog_def prog_defs[])
{
    char *line = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);

    int prog_count = 0;
    char* token;

    strcpy(line, buf);
    line[strlen(buf)] = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        int arg_count = 0;

        //The first time through we have to pass the line
        token = strtok(line, " ");

        //Each subsequent call we have to pass NULL
        //http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/
        line = NULL;

        //Start building the binary location string
        prog_defs[prog_count].bin = (char*)malloc(strlen(token) + DIRECTORY_LENGTH + 1);

        //Concatenate the directory prefix and command name
        strcat(prog_defs[prog_count].bin, DIRECTORY_PREFIX);
        strcat(prog_defs[prog_count].bin, token);

        //The first argument execvp will expect is the binary location itself
        //Redundant but if I wasn't too lazy to read the doc then I'd know why
        prog_defs[prog_count].args[arg_count++] = prog_defs[prog_count].bin;

        while(1)
        {
            prog_defs[prog_count].expecting_pipe = 0;

            //Check next token for end, pipe, IO redirection, or argument
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

            //If we've consumed all tokens
            if (token == NULL)
                break;

            //Pipe
            if (strcmp(token, "|") == 0)
            {
                prog_defs[prog_count - 1].expecting_pipe = 1;
                break;
            }

            //Regular argument
            prog_defs[prog_count].args[arg_count++] = token;
        }

        ++prog_count;

        if (token == NULL) break;
    }

    return prog_count;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char command[COMMAND_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};

    //Generic loop counter
    int x = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf(">");

        //Get the command
        gets(command);

        struct prog_def prog_defs[TOKEN_MAX];
        int prog_count = get_prog_defs(command, prog_defs);

        //Keep the previous out fd for the in of the subsequent process
        int prev_out_fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);

        for (x = 0; x < prog_count; ++x)
        {
            //Create a pipe for both processes to share
            int pipefd[2];

            if (x != prog_count -1)
            {
                pipe(pipefd);
            }

            prog_defs[x].pid = fork();

            if(prog_defs[x].pid == 0)
            {
                dup2(prev_out_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(pipefd[1]);

                if(x != prog_count - 1)
                {
                    dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(pipefd[0]);
                    close(pipefd[1]);
                }


                execvp(prog_defs[x].bin, prog_defs[x].args);
            prev_out_fd = pipefd[0];
            close(pipefd[1]);
            }

        close(prev_out_fd);

            prev_out_fd = pipefd[0];
            close(pipefd[1]);

        }

        printf("\n");

        for (x = 0; x < prog_count; ++x)
        {
            waitpid(prog_defs[x].pid, NULL, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this different from [your early question "Infinite pipe insanity" with a huge code dump](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14780894/2509)?

Comment: What's the point of the two lines following `execvp`? They will not be reached unless `execvp` fails, in which case you should deal with the error.

Answer (score 1):

You call `malloc` to get some memory for a string, which will be uninitialized, so contain random garbage.  You then call `strcat` which will attempt to append another string to the random garbage and almost certainly run off the end of the malloc'd space, leading to random confusing behavior and crashes.

You also use `prog_defs[prog_count - 1]` before ever incrementing `prog_count`, so the first time through the loop, (when `prog_count == 0`) this will write before the start of the array, which also leads to random confusing behavior and crashes.